# creating new object in select based on linked table in linq

Tags: c#, .net, linq

I have a table that has a FK to another table. I'm using a "view model" class that I want to return instead of the actual EF class. I know I can join the 2 tables and filter on the first table and then make a new view model in the select part based on the fields that I want, but can I do this without the join and instead use the linked table (via FK) in the select to create the view model instance?

ie. this works:

```
return (from a in context.Articles
                    join t in context.Topics on a.TopicID equals t.Id
                    where t.Name == topic
                    select new ArticleViewModel { Title = a.Title, Introduction = a.Introduction, Content = a.Content }).ToList();
```

Can I somehow create my ArticleViewModel with the Topics.Article link in a short and clean fashion:

```
return (from t in context.Topics
                    where t.Name == topic
                    select /*how can I create ArticleViewModel from t.Articles?*/ t.Articles).ToList();
```

Comment: Do you mean: how can I use navigation properties instead of joins? If so, you should show more details. Like, what type of LINQ is this, what do the classes look like and how are they related (1:n, n:1)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not HQL but Linq, I don't think you can do a select many in HQL, so your left with doing the join, or a sub query...

```
context.Topics.Where(x => x.Name.Equals(topic))
              .SelectMany(y => y.Articals)
              .Select(z => new ArticalViewModel { Title = z.Title , etc.. });
```

Answer (score 1):

It seems you have a DbContext

- with a DbSet of Articles. Each Article has a Topic.
- with a DbSet of Topics. Each Topic has a collection of Articles that belongs to the topic.
- And you want all articles that belong to a topic with the value of variable topic.

If you use entity framework and you have a one to many relation like you have in your Topic class, the "many" part has a foreign key to the "one" and the "one" part has a virtual ICollection of the "many" part

An Article belongs to exactly one Topic. An article "has" a Topic.

A topic has a collection of articles. Each item of the collection belongs to the topic.

This is designed as follows:

```
public class Article
{
    public int Id {get; set;}       // by convention will become primary key
    public int TopicId {get; set;}  // by convertion will become foreign key to Topic
    public Topic Topic {get; set;}  // an article "has" a Topic
    public string Title {get; set;}
    public string Introduction {get; set;}
    // etc.
}

public class Topic
{
    public int Id {get; set;}       // by convention primary key

    public virtual ICollection<Article> Articles {get; set;}
    ...
    // other Topic properties
}

public class MyDbContext : DbContext
{
    public DbSet<Topic> Topics {get; set;}
    public DbSet<Article> Articles {get; set;}
}
```

The following Linq statement will get your sequence of ArticleViewModel items
(I put them in small steps so it's clear what happens

```
using (var context = new MyDbContext(...))
{
    IQueryable<Article> articlesOfTopicsWithTopicName = context.Topics
        .Where(topc=> topc.Name == myTopicName)
        .SelectMany(topic => topic.Articles);
```

Whenever you have a sequence of type A and each A has a sequence of type B, and you want all B objects, you use SelectMany.

```
    IQueryable<ArticleViewModel> requestedItems =
        articlesOfTopicsWithTopicName.Select(article =>
            new ArticleViewModel()
            {
                Title = article.Title,
                Introduction = article.Introduction,
                ...
            }
    // delayed execution, nothing has been performed yet
    return requestedItems.ToList();
    // execute and return the list
}
```

If you use the database profiler, you will see that that selectMany will do a join on the foreign key in articles with the primary key in topic

Comment: So basically it's just less code for me to join on my own like I did above to get what I'm looking for in as small amount of code as possible.

Comment: no, I just wrote it in small steps. You can write it in one Linq statement, first the Where, then the SelectMany, where you can put them in objects of ArticleViewModel